# Is it possible in Django to grab a field from the first foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to optimize my Django query. Right now, I'm grabbing all products, then looping through them and making a separate query for the 'feature' image url.

Is there a way to grab the url for the 'Image' foreign key object where feature = True in the original query?

**Current Code:**

```
products = Product.objects.values('id')

products_list = []
​
for product in products:
​
    image_url = Image.objects.filter(product=product["id"]).order_by('-feature').values("url").first().get("url", None)

    image = resize_image(image_url, 500)

    products_list.append({
        "id": product["id"]
        "image": image,
    })

return Response({ "products": products_list }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**What I wish I could do:**

```
products = Product.objects.values('id', 'images__url')

​products_list = []

for product in products:

    image = resize_image(product["images__url"], 500)

    products_list.append({
        "id": product["id"]
        "image": image,
    })

return Response({ "products": products_list }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I try this, it seems to return a Product for each Image, which is not at all what I want.

To remedy this I tried to add a .distinct('id') on the end, but then I got this error:

```
NotImplementedError('annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.')
```

After that I wasn't sure how to proceed, or if this is possible?

Models (for reference):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="images")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    feature = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT: Added some more code for context**

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you want to include products that do not have any images? What will you be doing with the resulting products?

Comment: @IainShelvington technically all the products should have images, but I would want to filter out ones that don't as a precaution anyway.

Comment: @IainShelvington I'll be returning the values to the front end for display, but there are a few other things that need to be modified before it gets returned. for example, calculating a profit field from retail price and price. I omitted some of this to simplify my question.

Comment: @IainShelvington in case it helps, each product does eventually need to be returned as an object of its own with an image field along with others (in case you were thinking of suggesting the values_list option for grabbing images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this query in a values lookup is hard as you will not return any products that do not have featured images

You can use `prefetch_related` to pre-populate the result of reverse relationship lookups

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('images')
for product in products:
    print(product.images.all()) # This will not perform an additional query
```

You can filter the queryset that populates the reverse relationship by using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) objects

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'images',
    queryset=Image.objects.filter(feature=True),
    to_attr='featured_images'
))
for product in products:
    print(product.featured_images.all()) # Will return all featured images
```

We can use a distinct clause to only return 1 image for each product

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'images',
    queryset=Image.objects.filter(feature=True).order_by('product').distinct('product'),
    to_attr='featured_image'
))
```

Now in your template you can loop over this attribute and only get one image back

```
{% for image in product.featured_image.all %}
    {{ image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```